# Can't loop through results in MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm confused and I'll try to explain without confusing you too.

I have multiple tables joined in my query, which work fine in SQL and as expected. 
(In this instance there are two rows that live in the table 'projects_underground') and their values are *'Elephant & Castle'* and *'Lambert North'*).

I need to loop through the results of the `$row['underground_name']` array but for the life of me, I can't get it to work or understand where I am going wrong.

I can loop through ALL rows, but that gives me twice of everything, including everything in the 'Projects' table — which seems incredibly inefficient. As I only need the first row from the 'Projects' table. But if I loop through the `$row['underground_name']` I get no values from the 'projects' — at the moment it feels like it's one or the other?

Is it possible to loop through just and only the `$row['underground_name']` array?

Here's my code — thanks for your help,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM projects 
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_underground ON projects.projects_id = projects_underground.projects_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN underground ON underground.underground_id = projects_underground.underground_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN natrail ON projects.natrail_id = natrail.natrail_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dlr ON projects.dlr_id = dlr.dlr_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN overground ON projects.overground_id = overground.overground_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tram ON projects.tram_id = tram.tram_id LEFT JOIN river ON projects.river_id = river.river_id 
WHERE projects.name = 'Imperial War Museum'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $r = $row['underground_name'];

    }
```

Comment: Can you run the query in a MySQL IDE and show us the results?

Comment: Sure — screenshot is here... http://dev.museums-london.com/Query-Screenshot.png (I have shortened the query to not * everything from Projects — but just the 'name' for sake of simplicity).

Comment: You need to actually post the results here rather than providing a screenshot. That was the entire question is preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: your question is pretty vague, is `LIMIT 1` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

$row['underground_name'] isn't going to be a PHP array coming out of the database so you won't be able to iterate over it. If it's stored as json, then when you decode it you'll have an array to work with and foreach{} will get the job done.  If it's a smaller, more defined dataset you can store with a delimeter and then explode that row result to create a bonafide array....but otherwise, you're dealing with a string....and that string is flat.

Here's a quick PseudoCode to get you on the right track. Sometimes it helps to lay it all out like this,...then you can print_r/var_dump along the way to visualize your data a bit better.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $q = $row['fieldQ'];
    $r = json_decode($row['underground_name']);
    foreach($r AS $k => $v){
        //this is the loop you're looking for
    }
    $s = $row['fieldS'];
    $t = $row['fieldT'];   //etc,...etc.
}
```

Comment: It's my understanding that the results from mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) push out an associative array? — $row['underground_name'] $row being the array and ['underground_name'] being the key?. D'you mean to say that a running a foreach loop on the $row['underground_name'] would do the trick?  Many thanks for your help, I know newbies ask the most boring questions!

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. $row is the array itself ['undergroundname'] is the key.  So from the db, $row['underground'] name is going to be a string.  
But, if it weren't a string,...if you had stored it with json,...then json_decode that string,...then you would have the array you're looking for within the $row array.

Then, yes exactly,...run a foreach{} on just $row['underground_name']

Comment: I updated the answer with a quick sample of what's going on. It does assume that the data in the 'underground_name' field is ready to work with, as I said,..it doesn't have to be json, but you will need to create an array out of whatever it is,...json would be a sane place to start. serialize would work too, but I don't like it as much, and for a simple, one-dimensional array within 'underground_name',...just using a delimiter and explode is the simplest with the least overhead.